# Need advice on sending string to function

Tags: c

I am kind of new to c , but i cant figure out how to send this string to the function. I tried several things but it tells me it is expecting something

```
    program.c: In function ‘main’:
    program.c:48:87: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘long’

       char string1[] =
 "This is process %d with ID %ld and parent id %ld\n", i,  (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());

    write(wrfd1,string1, strlen(string1));
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Here is some inforamtion on string manipulation in C http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html If you still have problems after reading this, feel free to add to your question.

Comment: I didn't know you could construct a string literal like that. It's done in a printf and the line, but I haven't seen it like that before. Why not just embed in the variables in the string. ex. char string[] = "This is the process " + " i;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
int length = 100;
char string1[length];
if(sprintf(string1, "This is process %d with ID %ld and parent id %ld\n", i,  (long)getpid(), (long)getppid())) {
   write(wrfd1,string1, length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is:

```
 (long)getppid())
```

the bracket number doesn't match.

Another one is that you cannot assign a string like this:

```
int a = 100;
char str[] = "A is %d", a;
```

You should use 'sprintf' to do this, as mentioned above.